# Why does my text print black instead of grey in Word 2010?

Tags: printing, microsoft-word-2010

I'm writing a document in Word 2010 and I need some of the text to print as grey. It's designed so but when I print, all text comes out black. I don't see anything in the Printer Settings. How do I keep that from happening? I need to deliver this document to a client and want to make sure it prints the proper colors for him also.

Comment: If you need to send a file to someone else and they don't need to edit it you're probably better off sending it as a PDF. That format is designed to look the same everywhere. Word docs can change depending on the computer you open it on.

Comment: are you printing in B&W, color, or Greyscale? any option by B&W should work.

Comment: The client needs to be able to edit it, I did end up finding something about greyscale in the printer settings so I'm guessing I'll have to do tests here and with them. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Given that you grey is printing as black, there is a good chance that somewhere you have a setting to print everything as black and white.  Check Word, your printer drivers, and directly on your printer front panel to see if something is set to print black and white only.  I've experienced the same thing, and I always find a setting that is set to print in black and white only.